# Something went wrong: 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, parameters, foreign-keys

I am trying to insert the following information into the tables I created (below):

```
    try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO organizer (name, contact) VALUES (%s,%s);", (name, contact))
        conn.commit()
        dbMenu.entryconfig("Clear All Data", state=NORMAL)
        printInLogPanel("insertion successfull")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))

    try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO event (summary, start_time, location, organizer, num_alarms) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);",(e[2], e[5], e[3], e[1], e[4]))
        conn.commit()
        dbMenu.entryconfig("Clear All Data", state=NORMAL)
        print("Events stored")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
```

My Tables :

```
CREATE TABLE organizer (
org_id int primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(60) not null,
contact varchar(60) not null
)


CREATE TABLE event (
event_id int primary key auto_increment, 
summary varchar(60) not null, 
start_time datetime not null, 
location varchar(60), 
organizer int, 
num_alarms int, 
foreign key(organizer) references organizer(org_id) on delete cascade)
```

When I try to execute the Insert commands I get the following error:

```
Something went wrong: 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a 
foreign key constraint fails (`wqazi`.`event`, CONSTRAINT 
`event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`organizer`) REFERENCES `organizer` 
(`org_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I've noticed that for table 2 event organizer is an int so im guessing we have to pass the org_id into it somehow but I just don't understand how.

Comment: Please don't ask a question until you have googled your error message without your specific names & read many answers of many hits & read all relevant parts of the manual, which in this case is probably the first page about FKs. Then report how that doesn't answer your question. See [ask]. Also please tag whatever other language you are using. Also please read & act on [mcve]. PS Basic debugging says echo input & output. The FK says event organizer must be an organizer id. It isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the value of `event`.`organizer` you try to insert into table `event` doesn't exist in table `organizer`.`org_id`